# Exporting a thematic raster in byte format to use with GUIDOS toolbox

Tags: geotiff-tiff, bit-depth

I am trying to export some thematic rasters to use them with GUIDOS Toolbox (specifically the MSPA segmentation functions) - http://forest.jrc.ec.europa.eu/download/software/guidos/

GUIDOS requires the images to be GeoTIFF format, with pixels of data type Byte. It reads 0 bytes as no data (optional), 1 byte as background and 2 bytes as foreground and performs segmentation only on foreground pixels.

In Arc I have rasters with values 2=foreground, 1=background - although changing these is trivial. How do I go about converting these to byte and exporting to GeoTIFF? The lowest pixel depth Arc seems to support for TIFF is 8bit.

Does anyone have a workaround, or some third-party recommendations to do this pre-processing for GUIDOS?

Comment: 1 byte = 8 bits, and you would need at leat 2 bits to store 0,1 and 2

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand how the byte format works. My understanding from reading the GUIDOS documentation is that it looks for a number of bytes, not a numerical representation. Does this mean the raste needs to have variable pixel depth? I'm probably way off the mark here!

Comment: What I mean is that if your export in 8bit (e.g. with copy raster) your data can be used by GUIDOS.

Comment: That was what I thought, but I spent days trying different ways of exporting, and tried 8 bit unsigned many times but to no avail. I've just managed to make it work by mosaicking to new raster on a foreground and a background layer, and writing the output directly as 8-bit TIFF, but no idea why is wasn't behaving with exporting an existing raster...